# Returning One custom taxonomy term name

Tags: custom-taxonomy, loop, templates, terms

I have a custom taxonomy called cities and right now the only city is las vegas. I am trying to use the code in question to echo "Las Vegas" - for the posts that are associated - on the search results page, taxonomy page and single post page.

Las vegas wouldnt be the only city, but each post should only be associated with 1 city therefore I just need the term associated with the post. As of now with the code Im using, the term is echoing for every post, even those not in the "City" category.

```
<?php  $terms = get_terms( 'city-type' );
 if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
       echo '<span>' . $term->name . '</span>';      
     }
 }; ?>
```

Im using in the loop, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fetching all the terms of your taxonomy, Use this instead :

```
 $terms = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'city-type');
  if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
     foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
       echo '<span>' . $term->name . '</span>';      
     }
  }
```

**Note :**  First argument to the function is id of the post, get_the_ID() will work fine on single post details page and within loops. Function reference on [WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms)

Comment: How would i display 2 terms?